# Javascript Library for hierarchical flowchart

Tags: graphics, javascript

Do you know any Javascript libraries which can present graph visually in a web page?

Clarification: by graphs I mean something like workflow trees or decision trees. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Gonçalo, I take it you want something that renders this kind of tree?
http://www.wem.com.au/images/tree_120306.jpg

Answer (score 5):

I've been doing some research, looking for a JS component that would handle the live creation of flow charts / decision trees, mxGraph looks pretty handy: http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html

Disclaimer: I have no relationship at all with the vendor, other than having searched the net for something suitable.

Comment: not free and not even cheap :(

Comment: No, but that wasn't the question!

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't the question, so +1 to cancel out the downvote.

Comment: @GonçaloVeiga: But you didn't mention a price limit.

Answer (score 1):

Dojo Charting:

- [tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/) (warning: this test server set up for debugging)
- [my articles on SitePen's blog](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/author/elazutkin/) (disclamer: I am the principle developer of this package).

Stand-alone Dojo charting widgets with links to the same test server:

- [analog gauge](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/widget/tests/test_AnalogGaugeWidget.html)
- [bar gauge](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/widget/tests/test_BarGaugeWidget.html) (variation of the bullet chart).

**EDIT:** responding to the latest edit of the question: Dojo Charting does not support flow charts directly. There are several projects that did just that using Dojo GFX, but nobody contributed it back — try to Google for it.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [proof-of-concept](http://jameslab.moveable.com/ajaxio/) box and connector program using [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) years ago. It's kind of crappy, and I never finished it, but it's proof it can be done. You're welcome to it.

Comment: that is really nice, even for a demo.  Very cool.

Comment: Look at the posting date. Things can't last forever.

Comment: @Diodeus: And that's why there's a good practice on stack overflow to not make a link the content of your answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll go back to 2008 and remember that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JSFlowChart...

Create flowchart using only HTML GUI. Functions are written in JavaScript with the help of JQuery. Drawing source is in HTML and visible. Program can be used locally if open the index.htm in browser.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsflowchart/

Answer (score 0):

We used [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) in our last project.  It's free and has a lot of neat features, check it out!

**EDIT:** Charts is the component that allows statistical type graphs, scatter plots and other charting stuff.  I didn't realize you were looking for a flowchart / hierarchy based graph.

Comment: Which component are you referring to? Charts? I'm not finding any component which could build graphs.

Answer (score 0):

SO uses [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), which I think is pretty awesome, and am looking to use in an upcoming company project

**edit:** Missed the "hierarchical" part. Would still recommend flot for linear though

Comment: Flot is a great lib, just not for trees.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [following library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/graphic_javascript_tree.aspx) a while back and it implements walker's algorithm nicely.  It might be a bit dated though.

Answer (score 0):

I think JQuery has some solutions to it, but I would say do it in Flex, it's awesome for these kind of scenarios. There are even an open source solution to Flex. And it's quite easy also, only look in the Adobe documentation.

Answer (score 0):

How about [InfoVis](http://thejit.org/)?  (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911903/jquery-or-extjs-plugins-for-creating-organization-chart).)