# Where can I find jQuery or Ext plugins for creating organization charts?

Tags: jquery, extjs, charts, organization

I know we can create an organization chart with [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html).

But my client's server doesn't have an Internet connection.

Are there any jQuery or Ext plugins for creating an organization chart?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have successfully used [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/) to create a graph that looks very similar to that.  As implied by the name, it is only Javascript and you can host it internally.  Since it is very customizable, there is a bit of a learning curve to getting your data in the correct format and the interface the way you'd like.  Look at [this demo](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html) for a tree-like structure which could be used for an organization.

Comment: This is the answer, tsurahman.  InfoVis looks nice!

Comment: best JS visualization library, hands down

Comment: jit is so heavy though. is it possible to lode the code just for that org chart piece?

Comment: @jellyfishtree - it is certainly possible, but also highly impractical

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there is. See http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery OrgChart` is a plugin that allows you to render structures with nested elements in a easy-to-read tree structure:

1. You can view a demo of this here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html
2. you can view the github repository here: https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart

Answer (score 0):

Seriously.. the [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/builder/) is superb. Just extend as necessary

Answer (score 0):

I have forked jOrgChart for the Ext JS users and created ExtJSOrgChart. Please check it out and provide your feedback.
https://github.com/shaikhmshariq/ExtJSOrgChart

Answer (score 0):

I like http://www.highcharts.com/

HighCharts extension for ExtJS 4
joekuan.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/highcharts-extension-for-extjs-4/?relatedposts_exclude=4038