# HTML draw flow diagram

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I am looking for the best approach to draw some flows in HTML. This is for a user facing website where they select some options and then they see some numbers/entities connected by arrows, pulled from some data table. It doesn't need to be too fancy but flexible (# entities changes).

What is the best tool for this? JS, HTML5, PHP, CSS?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944723/javascript-flowchart-flow-diagram-lib or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363592/javascript-library-for-hierarchical-flowchart?

Answer (score 1):

I'd also have a look at [D3](http://d3js.org/) tools (data driven documents) - a javascript library which allows all manner of graphs and charts - flow and otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here are most commonly used online tools to draw flow diagram in html

http://www.smashingapps.com/2011/08/26/45-free-online-tools-to-create-charts-diagrams-and-flowcharts.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HTML, use embed **SVG in HTML5** context.

For instance  [Drawing flowcharts with CSS and SVG](https://web.archive.org/web/20130328172920/http://www.minimalg.it:80/blog/2012/web-development/drawing-flowcharts-with-css-and-svg/).

Comment: Link mentioned in your answer is 404, any idea if there is updated link?

Comment: @hagrawal I updated the link with one from the internet archive