# I want to draw a flow chart using HTML, what are the best packages out there

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I want to draw a flow chart in my app using HTML. I was wondering if there are libraries or examples out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't be possible in pure HTML.  You will have to use javascript to some extent, possibly CSS as well.  There are many javacript charting libraries out there to help (some free, some paid) - depending on the task you need.  Here is one free one:  [flowchart.js](http://flowchart.js.org/)

And this post might help:

- [10 Javascript libraries to draw your own diagrams](http://modeling-languages.com/javascript-drawing-libraries-diagrams/)

Also these SO answers might also help you:

- [Javascript flowchart diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944723/javascript-flowchart-flow-diagram-lib?rq=1)
- [HTML draw flow diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725850/html-draw-flow-diagram?rq=1)